# How to stream audio in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I need to stream audio from this link on windows phone 
http://s4.voscast.com:8430/
I didn't get any proper solution. I have use AudioTrack and BackgroundAudioPlayer but this is  not streaming audio from this type of link.

Comment: Please include the code you have tried

Comment: @AlexS its simple using AudioTrack class.Nothing more